# Python: List not correct after appending lines

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to append lines to an empty list reading from a file, and I've already stripped the lines of returns and newlines, but what should be one line is being entered as two separate items into the list.

```
DNA = open('DNAGCex.txt')
DNAID = []
DNASEQ = []
for line in DNA:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.lstrip()
    if line.startswith('>')==True:
        DNAID.append(line)
    if line.startswith('>')==False:
        DNASEQ.append(line)
print DNAID
print DNASEQ
```

And here's the output

> ['>Rosalind_6404', '>Rosalind_5959', '>Rosalind_0808']
>   ['CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGA', 'TCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG', 'CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCA', 'ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC', 'CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAG', 'TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT']

I want it to look like this:

> ['>Rosalind_6404', '>Rosalind_5959', '>Rosalind_0808']
>   ['CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGATCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG', 'CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC', 'CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT']

Here is the source material, just remove the ''s:

> ['>Rosalind_6404'
>   CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGA
>   TCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
>   '>Rosalind_5959'
>   CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCA
>   ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>   '>Rosalind_0808'
>   CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAG
>   TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please shorten your example unless there is some reason we need to do long lines of DNA-looking stuff ... and try to be clearer what you're looking for; as rendered, output and desired output are identical as far as I can see.  I don't know this is a cut/paste issue or a formatting problem.

Comment: Please clean up the input material you posted into an easily copy-paste-able text blob; you shouldn't make others do this for you.

Comment: @Foon - The desired `list` has some elements combined into longer strings (agreed that it's not easy to spot, though).

Comment: I should have shortened the example text, but, regarding the input, the use of > to do block quotes interferes with keeping the input as close to the original as possible. Also, I didn't want to add any extra newline or return chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the `.lstrip()` and `.rstrip()` into a single `.strip()` call.

Then, you were thinking that `.append()` both added lines to a list and joined lines into a single line.  Here, we start `DNASEQ` with an empty string and use `+=` to join the lines into a long string:

```
DNA = open('DNAGCex.txt')
DNAID = []
DNASEQ = []
for line in DNA:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('>'):
        DNAID.append(line)
        DNASEQ.append('')
    else:
        DNASEQ[-1] += line
print DNAID
print DNASEQ
```

Comment: Your implementation works, but I'm relatively inexperienced. Could you explain the functionality of: DNASEQ[-1] += line ?

Comment: That accesses the last element of `DNASEQ` - which is a string - and concatenates the current content of `line` onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Within each iteration of the loop, you're only looking at a certain line from the file. This means that, although you certainly are appending lines that don't contain a linefeed at the end, you're still appending one of the file's lines at a time. You'll have to let the interpreter know that you want to combine certain lines, by doing something like setting a flag when you first start to read in a DNASEQ and clearing it when the next DNAID starts.

```
for line in DNA:
    line = line.strip() # gets both sides
    if line.startswith('>'):
        starting = True
        DNAID.append(line)
    elif starting:
        starting = False
        DNASEQ.append(line)
    else:
        DNASEQ[-1] += line
```